# how to use Sum , count distinct , group by together?

Tags: sql

Use this to create a SQL query to:

**Show me the count of distinct products in each business unit that generated a total revenue of over £1M in 2020.**

**TABLE_Orders**

```
Date          ...   (date ('YYYY-MM-DD)) 

Order_Id      ...   int (5)  

Business_id   ...   int(10)  

Product_id    ...  int(10)  

Quantity      ...   int(4) 

Revenue       ...   decimal (10,2)

...............

..............

**TABLE_business**

Business_id       ...   int(10)

Business_Name     ...   varchar(50)

Business_Unit     ...   varchar(25)

Business_Address  ...   varchar (250)

......
```

i created query to find distinct product_id like this

```
select b.Business_id,b.business_name, b.Business_unit, o.Countt,o.revenues from Table_Busines b join
(select  business_id,  count(distinct product_id) Countt ,sum(revenue) revenues  from Table_orders 
where year(date)=2000
group by  business_id
having sum(revenue)>1000000) o  on b.Business_id=o.Business_id
```

i dont know my code is correct or note ? bcs question asks for  each **business-unit** but my code is for each **business_ID** , anyone can help?.

Comment: share sample data with expected output

Comment: there is no sample data only this question and i just want to know if there is a way to change Business_id with Business_unit in subquery?